# Ionic 3 Native FIle image view not working

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

Images in the android's external root directory not showing. I can access the name of the image but i cant get the image to show on the device.
Here is my HTML file

```
<ion-item *ngFor="let status of user_statuses" (click)="showDetails(status)">
    <ion-thumbnail item-start>
      <img data-ng-src="{{status.nativeURL}}">
    </ion-thumbnail>
    <h2>{{status.name}}</h2>
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

And here is my Typescript file

```
goToDir(){   
this.fileCtrl.listDir(this.fileCtrl.externalRootDirectory,'Whatsapp/Media/.Statuses').then(
  (list) => {
    this.user_statuses = list;
  }
);  }
```

I would really like to know what i am doing wrong please.

Comment: Any errors thrown? What prints console.log?

Comment: I am running this project on an emulator so i can't really view the console

Comment: I don't really know the right way to do what i wanna do. The error of my code originates from <img data-ng-src="{{status.nativeURL}}">

Comment: So run your app using `ionic cordova run android -c`, you should have a console.log output.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. Instead of `<img src.....` i used `<img data-ng-src....`
Thanks for your help!